# How to use jquery to show pie charts on leaflet when checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet

I am trying to figure how to make the pie chart (that I created using leaflet) appear and disappear when a certain checkbox is checked. Example: When the first checkbox with id="data" is checked, the pie charts will appear whereas when the checkbox is unchecked, the pie chart will disappear. I written a javascript code in the head section of the html code which function is to do something when the boxes are checked/unchecked, just that currently there are alert codes in it. I created the pie charts which is in a  pie chart code here  at the bottom section. I just cant figure out how to activate the pie chart when the id="data" is checked. I tried putting the pie chart code in the if else statement but it wouldnt work. If you happen to know of a solution, do let me know.

```
// HTML code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Map Testing</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
        crossorigin=""/>
        <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
        <!-- Cdn for jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Event handling of checking of checkboxes -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('input[id="data"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        alert("data checked");
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        alert("data unchecked");
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="imports"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        alert("imports checked");
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        alert("imports unchecked");
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="exports"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        alert("exports checked");
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        alert("exports unchecked");
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="markers"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        alert("markers checked");
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        alert("markers unchecked");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <!-- Access style.css file in the same folder -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="hamburger-menu">
                    <div class="line line-1"></div>
                    <div class="line line-2"></div>
                    <div class="line line-3"></div>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="data"> Data
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="imports"> Imports
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="exports"> Exports
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="markers"> Markers
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="map">
        <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
        </div>
        <script src="http://sashakavun.github.io/leaflet-canvasicon/leaflet-canvasicon.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet-piechart.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        L.piechartMarker(
          L.latLng([20.594, 78.962]), // lat lng for India
          {
              radius: 40,
              data: [
                  { name: 'Tobacco', value: 25, style: { fillStyle: 'rgba(0,0,255,1)', strokeStyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,.95)'} },
                  { name: 'Whiskey', value: 35, style: { fillStyle: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)', strokeStyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,.95)'} },
                  { name: 'Beer', value: 20, style: { fillStyle: 'rgba(0,255,0,1)', strokeStyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,.95)'} },
                  { name: 'Cigar', value: 30, style: { fillStyle: 'rgba(255,255,0,1)', strokeStyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,.95)'} },
                  { name: 'Others', value: 5, style: { fillStyle: 'rgba(255,228,181,1)', strokeStyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,.95)'} },
              ]
          }
      ).addTo(mymap);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

// leaflet-piechart.js
/*global L */
(function () {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Piechart Icon
     * @type {L.PiechartIcon}
     * @extends {L.CanvasIcon}
     */
    L.PiechartIcon = L.CanvasIcon.extend({
        options: {
            iconSize: [48, 48],
            iconAnchor: [24, 24],
            popupAnchor: [24, 24],
            className: 'leaflet-piechart-icon',
            valueField: 'value',
            nameField: 'name'
            /*
             data: [
                 {
                     name: 'Value',
                     value: 20, // Percentage or raw value
                     style: {
                         fillStyle: 'rgba(255,0,0,.5)',
                         strokeStyle: 'rgba(255,0,0,.5)',
                         lineWidth: 1
                     }
                 },
             ...
             ]
             */
        },

        /**
         * @param {HTMLCanvasElement} icon
         * @param {string} type
         */
        _setIconStyles: function (icon, type) {
            var data = this.options.data;
            if ((type == 'icon') && data && L.Util.isArray(data) && icon.getContext) {
                var ctx = icon.getContext('2d');
                var size = L.point(this.options.iconSize);
                var center = size.divideBy(2);
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size.x, size.y);

                var valueField = this.options.valueField;
                var total = this._getTotal(data, valueField);
                var x = center.x;
                var y = center.y;
                if (total) {
                    var radius = Math.min(x, y);
                    var fraction = Math.PI / total * 2;
                    var startAngle = -Math.PI / 2;
                    var stopAngle;
                    var style;
                    for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        style = data[i].style || this._getStyle(i, l);
                        this._applyStyle(ctx, style);
                        stopAngle = fraction * data[i][valueField] + startAngle;
                        ctx.arc(x, y, radius - Math.ceil((style.lineWidth || 0) / 2), startAngle, stopAngle);
                        ctx.stroke();
                        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
                        startAngle = stopAngle;
                        ctx.fill();
                        ctx.closePath();
                    }
                }
            }
            L.CanvasIcon.prototype._setIconStyles.apply(this, arguments);
        },

        /**
         * @param {Object[]} data Array of objects
         * @param {string} field Field to summarize
         * @returns {number}
         * @private
         */
        _getTotal: function (data, field) {
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
                total += (+data[i][field]);
            }
            return total;
        },

        /**
         * Applies context style
         * @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} ctx
         * @param {Object} props
         * @private
         */
        _applyStyle: function (ctx, props) {
            for (var i in props) {
                ctx[i] = props[i];
            }
        },

        /**
         * Generates style for chart segment
         * @param {number} segment Segment number
         * @param {number} total Total segments
         * @returns {{fillStyle: string, strokeStyle: string, lineWidth: number}}
         * @private
         */
        _getStyle: function (segment, total) {
            /**
             * Converts an HSL color value to RGB. Conversion formula
             * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
             * Assumes h, s, and l are contained in the set [0, 1] and
             * returns r, g, and b in the set [0, 255].
             * @url http://axonflux.com/handy-rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-c
             *
             * @param {number} h The hue
             * @param {number} s The saturation
             * @param {number} l The lightness
             * @return {string} The RGB representation
             */
            var hslToRgb = function (h, s, l) {
                var r, g, b;
                if (s == 0) {
                    r = g = b = l; // achromatic
                } else {
                    var hue2rgb = function (p, q, t) {
                        if (t < 0) t += 1;
                        if (t > 1) t -= 1;
                        if (t < 1 / 6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
                        if (t < 1 / 2) return q;
                        if (t < 2 / 3) return p + (q - p) * (2 / 3 - t) * 6;
                        return p;
                    };

                    var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
                    var p = 2 * l - q;
                    r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1 / 3);
                    g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
                    b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1 / 3);
                }

                return Math.round(r * 255) + ',' + Math.round(g * 255) + ',' + Math.round(b * 255);
            };

            var angle = 360 / (total * 2.5);
            var offset = (segment % 2) * total;
            var hue = (angle * (offset + (segment - (segment % 2)))) / 360;
            var rgb = hslToRgb(hue, 0.7, 0.5);
            return {
                fillStyle: 'rgba(' + rgb + ',.5)',
                strokeStyle: 'rgba(' + rgb + ',.7)',
                lineWidth: 1
            };
        }
    });

    /**
     * Pie char Icon factory
     * @param {Object} options
     * @returns {L.PiechartIcon}
     */
    L.piechartIcon = function (options) {
        return new L.PiechartIcon(options);
    };

    /**
     * Pie chart Marker
     * @type {L.Marker}
     */
    L.PiechartMarker = L.Marker.extend({
        options: {
            icon: null,
            radius: 20,
            riseOnHover: true
        },

        initialize: function (latlng, options) {
            var opts = {};
            L.Util.extend(opts, options);
            if (opts.radius) {
                var diameter = opts.radius * 2;
                opts.iconSize = [diameter, diameter];
                opts.iconAnchor = [opts.radius, opts.radius];
            }
            opts.icon = L.piechartIcon(opts);
            L.Marker.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [latlng, opts]);
        }
    });

    /**
     * Pie chart Marker factory
     * @param {L.LatLng} latlng
     * @param {Object} options
     * @returns {L.PiechartMarker}
     */
    L.piechartMarker = function (latlng, options) {
        return new L.PiechartMarker(latlng, options);
    }

}());
```

Comment: Check console I think you can get this error L.piechartMarker is not a function

Comment: I cant include L.piechartMarker in the if else?

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Map Testing</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
        crossorigin=""/>
        <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
        <!-- Cdn for jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Event handling of checking of checkboxes -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('input[id="data"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        $(".leaflet-marker-icon").show();
                        alert("data checked");
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                         $(".leaflet-marker-icon").hide();
                        alert("data unchecked");
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="imports"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                       $(".leaflet-marker-icon").show();
                        alert("imports checked");
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        $(".leaflet-marker-icon").hide();
                        alert("imports unchecked");
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="exports"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        $(".leaflet-marker-icon").show();
                        alert("exports checked");
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        $(".leaflet-marker-icon").hide();
                        alert("exports unchecked");
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="markers"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        $(".leaflet-marker-icon").show();
                        alert("markers checked");
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        $(".leaflet-marker-icon").hide();
                        alert("markers unchecked");
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
    #header {
      padding:0 1em;
    }
    body {
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
    }
    #description {
      line-height:0px;
      font-style:italic;
    }
    #map {
      top:120px;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      position:absolute;
      background:#fff;
    }
  </style>
        <!-- Access style.css file in the same folder -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="hamburger-menu">
                    <div class="line line-1"></div>
                    <div class="line line-2"></div>
                    <div class="line line-3"></div>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="data"> Data
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="imports"> Imports
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="exports"> Exports
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="markers"> Markers
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="map">

        </div>
        <script src="http://sashakavun.github.io/leaflet-canvasicon/leaflet-canvasicon.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet-piechart.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          (function () {
    var map = L.map('map', {
      zoom: 12,
      center: [20.594, 78.962]
    });
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' }).addTo(map);



      L.piechartMarker(
          L.latLng([20.594, 78.962]),
          {
               radius: 40,
              data: [
                  { name: 'Tobacco', value: 25, style: { fillStyle: 'rgba(0,0,255,1)', strokeStyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,.95)'} },
                  { name: 'Whiskey', value: 35, style: { fillStyle: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)', strokeStyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,.95)'} },
                  { name: 'Beer', value: 20, style: { fillStyle: 'rgba(0,255,0,1)', strokeStyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,.95)'} },
                  { name: 'Cigar', value: 30, style: { fillStyle: 'rgba(255,255,0,1)', strokeStyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,.95)'} },
                  { name: 'Others', value: 5, style: { fillStyle: 'rgba(255,228,181,1)', strokeStyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,.95)'} },
              ]
          }
      ).addTo(map);



  }());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if i check the boxes and uncheck it, the whole map disappears, what I meant is that only the pie chart should disappear but the map should still be around. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution, but actually it shouldnt be leaflet-marker-icon but instead should be leaflet-piechart icon. But either way, thanks.